# start-storybook: Permission denied

Tags: reactjs, storybook

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnc9Z.jpg

My storybook was working fine on Windows 10, while pushing to the server

sh: 1: start-storybook: Permission denied

root_app_0486GCHS-Des ign-L-801: /datadr ive/FE/censa-design-systen$ sudo npm run storybook

> democensa-bookel. 1.7 storybook
> start-storybook -p 6696

node: internal /modules/cjs/ Loader: 1631
throw err;

Error: Cannot find module *../dist/cis/server!
Require stack:

- /datadr ive/FE/censa-des1gn-systen/node_nodules/@storybook/ react /bin/ index. 15
  at Function. Module. _resolveFilename (node: internal /modules/cjs/loader:1628:15)
  at Function.Module. Load (node: internal /modules/cfs/ loader :873:27)
  at Module. require (node: internal /modules/cjs/Loader:1100:19)
  at require (node: internal /nodules/cis/helpers: 168: 13)
  at Object. canonynous> (/datadrive/FE/censa-des1gn-systen/node modules, @storybook/react/bin/ index. Js:3:1)
  at Module. compile (node: internal /modules/cs/ loader: 1198:14)
  at Object. Module. extensions. Js (node: Internal /modules;/cjs/10ader1252:10)
  at Module. load (nade: Internal /nodules,/cis/loader1076:32)
  at Function Module. load (node: internal /modules/cls/loader:911:12)
  at Function. executeUserEntryPoint [as runkain] (node: internal /modules,/run marr
  code: "MODULE NOT_FOUNDY ,
  requirestack: (

- 1datadrive/FE/censa-des gn-systen/node_modules storybook react /bin/ index. Js

Answer (score -1):

first delete your node_modules folder or rename it. And then again install node_modules by running `npm install`. Now should work fine.

Comment: i tried it multiples time then one more new issue comes.